# Problem reading nchar data from oracle database

Tags: oracle

I have an oracle database which nls character set is set to ALS32UTF8 and nls nchar character set is set to UTF8.

But however if i insert any data to a nvarchar column in a table.

Subsequent when i do a select the data i got is ???.

Why is this so?

The funny thing is that using TOAD i can read view the correct nvarchar data using the schema brower - > data

But if i use sql to do a select i get ???.

Any idea anyone and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

What is the NLS_LANG setting on your client? For a good reference on NLS parameters, read this [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/globalization/htdocs/nls_lang%20faq.htm) by Oracle. For additional reading on Unicode, see [this essay](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the clients NLS_LANG to utf.

sqlplus uses these environent variables (registry parameters on windows): 
(You may need to use sqlplusw.exe to use utf-8 on windows.)

NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
ORA_NCHAR_LITERAL_REPLACE=true

See also : [Inserting national characters into an oracle NCHAR or NVARCHAR column does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6509751/92018)