# mybatis text literal n without Tomcat parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, unicode, mybatis

I need to make an insert with a string literal n with mybatis.
The sql query would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, column)
VALUES ('1', n'value');
```

In mybatis right now I got something like this:

```
<insert id="createOne" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id" keyColumn="id">
    INSERT INTO table
        (
            id,
            column
        )
    VALUES
        (
            FBK_SQ_PAGOPA_CREDITOR_INFO_ID.nextval,
            #{value}
        )
</insert>
```

I'm not quite sure how can I use the n here... I already tried n#{value}, n'#{value}, n #{value} n${value} with no result.
My column type is NVARCHAR2 and I used this type to be able to use the € (eur) symbol with an old charset.

I cannot use this solution
[How to insert unicode to Oracle NVARCHAR using MyBatis with Spring integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698405/how-to-insert-unicode-to-oracle-nvarchar-using-mybatis-with-spring-integration/13723227#13723227)

because I the tomcat used in production is used for multiple project and the system manager said they will not edit the tomcat configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `jdbcType` or `typeHandler` explicitly in each parameter reference.

- `#{value,jdbcType=NVARCHAR}`
- `#{value,typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.NStringTypeHandler}`