# Persian character encoding in oracle database

Tags: oracle, unicode, utf-8, weblogic, farsi

I have got a problem with saving Persian characters like ("ی" or "ک") into oracle database. I receive correct encoding from a client, but when I insert the related record into the database, it will be saved with Arabic encoding like this ("ي").

The specifications of my application are:

- WebLogic application server 12c on Linux
- Oracle 11 g (thin driver)
- OpenJPA 2.2.2

I set the following properties into WebLogic setting file, but it did not work.

```
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AR8MSWIN1256
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: IIRC Oracle also has a locale that must be set on the server side.

Comment: I think it is an issue with the **client** characterset. Check the database characterset and set the client characterset as the same. Post the results of `select value from v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';` **-- locale-specific characterset**
`select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';` **-- database characterset** See http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/09/24/why-are-junk-values-displayed-in-my-client/

Comment: Do you have **both** exports of `NLS_LANG`? There should be only one.

Comment: Encoding of client is correct, it has problem with weblogic. result of two query is: AR8MSWIN1256. I set one of the NLS_LANG exports each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding following properties into weblogic setting ('JAVA_OPTIONS' part of setDomainEnv.sh file), my problem has been resolved by help of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509751/inserting-national-characters-into-an-oracle-nchar-or-nvarchar-column-does-not-w)

```
-Doracle.jdbc.defaultNChar=true 
-Doracle.jdbc.convertNcharLiterals=true
```