# How to set encoding to UTF16 in PySpark Oracle JDBC Connection

Tags: oracle, jdbc, pyspark, unicode, databricks

I'm trying to load the data from Oracle to Databricks but I encountered a Unicode character issue in PySpark it can't encode the Unicode character as per the format available in Oracle in fact it displays the replacement character as '▯'.In oracle the NLS_NCHAR_NCHARACTERSET=AL16UTF16.

I tried the [Inserting national characters into an oracle NCHAR or NVARCHAR column does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509751/inserting-national-characters-into-an-oracle-nchar-or-nvarchar-column-does-not-w) Oracle JDBC system property but it doesn't work in my case. I request you to please provide an alternative to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

option 1 - Use a jdbc option when you read data with spark:

```
spark.read.format("jdbc")...option("useUnicode", true).option("characterEncoding", "UTF-16")
```

option 2 - Use proper connection string:

```
url = "...?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-16"
spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", url)
```

Comment: Hi @YuriR it works for SQL but not for Oracle I tried both the options. Can you suggest any alternative please.

Comment: @Ahnvi is your table defined with utf-16 support? Try to query your db with pure python or java and see if you get correct characters.